# reading JSON element using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving a JSON object from a PHP get request. It looks like this:

```
data == {"user_id":"7","emp_type_id":[{"0":"11","1":"10"}]}
```

I need to access the items within emp_type_id ("11" and "10" in this case).

I am able to access user_id just fine using data["user_id"] but can't figure out how to get the other items. I tried variations of:

```
eti=data["emp_type_id"];
var myVar = eti[0];
```

I'll want to loop through all items in emp_type_id eventually and add them to a JS array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neal's answer will help, but I think you have other problems.  Your json structure looks wrong

```
a) data == {"user_id":"7","emp_type_id":[{"0":"11","1":"10"}]}
```

should it be

```
b) data == {"user_id":"7","emp_type_id":["11","10"]}
```

That is in english

a) emp_type_id an array of one object which has two fields `0` and `1`?

b) emp_type_id an array of two items with values `11` and `10`

If it should be b) then your json is wrong.

Comment: You might want to rephrase that - the JSON isn't 'wrong', it might be unnecessary, inefficient or complex, but it's certainly valid.

Comment: hmm i guess it should be b). i actually had that to start but then when i couldn't figure out how to get those values (thought they might need to have a key), i thought it was wrong and changed it to the other version (json_encode($emp_type_id, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); vs. json_encode($emp_type_id);). does this change how i access those values?

Comment: @no.go - OK I changed it "+structure" activated.

Comment: It's not wrong syntactically, but the OP might have had something else in mind ...

Comment: @vee -- yes it does!  If it is an array, as shown in b) then it it just is emp_type_id[x] for item x.  If not then it gets crazy.  See @James answer for more on this.

Comment: @Dan, yes I clearly meant there was a problem semantically.  @no.go found that unclear.  *shrug*

Comment: ok, it works now! i think my issue earlier when i was using b) was that i had an extra pair of quotes in the json. this works now: var eti=data["emp_type_id"]; alert(eti[0]); thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use a [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/For...in) loop

```
var data = {"user_id":"7","emp_type_id":[{"0":"11","1":"10"}]};
var eti = data["emp_type_id"];
var myVar = eti[0];
for(var entry in myVar){
  alert(entry + ":\t" + myVar[entry] );
}
```

[Running JSBIN Example](http://jsbin.com/urezu4/)

Comment: This will work, but I think it's best if he fixes his JSON like Hogan suggested in his post.

Answer (score 1):

data is an object that has two properties, user_id and emp_type_id.  emp_type_id is an array with one element (???), that element is an object with the properties 0 and 1.

There are two ways of reading a property from an object:

```
var prop = data['emp_type_id'];
var prop = data.emp_type_id;
```

If you have "weird" property names then you will have to use the square-bracket technique.

so

```
var prop0 = data.emp_type_id[0].0;
var prop1 = data.emp_type_id[0].1;
```

I'm concerned that "0" and "1" will fall under the category of "weird property names" so you might need to do

```
var prop0 = data.emp_type_id[0]["0"];
var prop1 = data.emp_type_id[0]["1"];
```

Comment: +1 - This answer makes it clear what was semantically wrong with the json he was using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var eti = data.emp_type_id;
var myVar = eti[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var eti = data.emp_type_id;
var myVar = eti[0];

for(var key in myVar){
    myVar[key];
}
```